# Exercise 4.3.13 on Frobenius morphisms in Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, flatness

Let $X$ be a smooth morphism over a scheme $S$ of positive characteristic $p > 0$.
The morphism $F_S: S \to S$ induced by the ring homomorphism
$O_S \to O_S : a \mapsto a^p$ the absolute
Frobenius of $S$. We let $X^{(p)} $ denote
the fibered product $X \times_S S$, where the second factor $S$ is endowed
with the structure of an S-scheme via the absolute
Frobenius $F_S : S \to S$. The relative Frobenius $F_{X/k} : X \to X^{(p)}$
fits in following diagram in [Definition 33.36.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CC6) from Stacks Project.

*Exercise 4.3.13* in Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves
asks of us to prove

(a) Show that $X^{(p)} \to S $ is smooth
(use Proposition 3.38).
(b) Let us suppose that $S$ is the spectrum of a field $k$. Let
$F_{X/k} : X \to X^{(p)}$ be the relative Frobenius.
Show that $F_{X/k}$ is flat at the rational
points of $X$ (use Proposition 2.27).
(c) Show that $F_{X/k}$ is faithfully flat, that is flat and surjective

and I'm having trouble in solving some parts there.

(a) follows simply from smoothness of $X \to S$ by base change.

(b) could work like this: $X$ is smooth and therefore at every point
rational point $x$ the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion of the stalk
$O_{X,x}$ at it's maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is

$$\hat{O}_{X,x} \cong k[[T_1,..., T_d]]  $$

with $d = \dim O_{X,x}.$

Therefore at $x$ the map on stalks $F_{X/k}: O_{X,x} \to O_{X,x}$ induces
a map on the completions $k[[T_1,..., T_d]]$ which should be determined
by $T_j \mapsto T_j^p$.

Why is the last map flat and how can I deduce the flatness of $F_{X/k}$ at $x$?
If $d=1$ then $k[[T_1]]$ is principal ideal domain and since the map
$k[[T_1]] \to k[[T_1]], T_1 \mapsto T_1^p$ is
torsion free therefore flat and we win. What about case $d > 1$ und how to
deduce flatness of  $F_{X/k}$ in $O_{X,x}$.

(c) No idea how to prove that $F_{X/k}$ flat. Flatness commutes base change
so that it's sufficient to show it at closed points. But not all closed points are
rational, so I not see how (b) helps.

Comment: There's a proof here for the flatness: https://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/relative-frobenius/ surjectivity is easy.

Comment: @LukasHeger: Thank you. Then for (b) we obtain the stronger statement that $ k[T_1,..., T_d ]]$ is even free as algebra over itself via Frobenius

Comment: Yeah, surjectivity follows just from observation that set theoretically the relative Frobenius is identity since the associated ring map pulls every prime ideal back to itself!

Comment: Do you have a hint for (c)?

Comment: The link I posted shows that the relative Frobenius is in this case a locally free morphism and hence flat.

Comment: Yes I noticed it now. The only point that still doesn't satisfy me is that I'm not really sure if the proof from the link is exactly the same as Liu intended the reader should solve it in the Exercise above. It seems natural that the part (c) should be somehow concluded making usage of part (b). I think the key is to make a base change to algebraic closure and to show (b) not for the original Frobenius but for the 'base changed' one $F_{X/k} \otimes \overline{k}: X \otimes \overline{k} \to X  \otimes \overline{k}^{(p)} $. Since it's rational points are $\overline{k}$-points

Comment: and the closed points of $X \otimes \overline{k}$ are exactly the $ \overline{k}$-points, $F_{X/k} \otimes \overline{k}$ is flat everywhere. (That's where we use (b) to conclude (c)) But $X \otimes \overline{k} \to X$ is faithfully flat, so $F_{X/k}$ is flat too. Should work like this... And one should check that Frobenius commutes with base change but that looks doable